# Is checking for true explicity bad by design?

Tags: javascript, weakly-typed

Is it considered bad to explicitly check for the boolean true. Would it be better to do a simple `if(success)` ?

I've seen various jokes made about how `if (someBoolean === true)` is horrible code in a strongly typed language but is it also considered bad in weakly typed languages?

This would apply for any weakly typed language that does type coercion on an if statement.

A specific example would be :

```
var onSuccess = function (JSONfromServer) {
    // explicitly check for the boolean value `true`
    if (JSONfromServer === true) {
         // do some things
    }
}

// pass it to an ajax as a callback
doSomeAjax(onSuccess);
```

[Edit]

In this particular case the success variable is any valid JSON returned from a server. So it could be anything. if its the boolean true then a success happened. If it's some error handling object then it will be handled. If it's something else then it will probably be handled quietly.

The question was is getting the server to return `true` as JSON and checking for a good way to handle the case where the action succeeded.

I wanted to avoid being specific to JavaScript & AJAX though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm in two minds about this myself.

In one respect, the code sample you've posted is good, because of the way Javascript handles type coercion.  A simple `if (success)` would enter the if block so long as `success` was *truthy* - e.g. a non-empty string would do the case.  The triple-equals guarantees that `success` is indeed the boolean value `true`, which is a stronger guarantee than you'd get with the shorter version (and probably one that you want).

However, if you *need* this - i.e. you don't know whether `success` will be a boolean, or a string, or an integer - I'd say that's a code smell in itself.  Regardless of how you perform the comparison, I'd always compare with a variable that's going to unavoidably be a boolean; at which point, it doesn't matter which form of comparison is used as they'd be equivalent.  In fact, I'd even introduce a "redundant" variable like so:

```
var successCount = items.size(); // or some other way to get an integer
var success = successCount > 0;
if (success) {
   ...
}
```

So, erm, yeah.  I don't think anyone could really complain about the (explicit) use of `===` in the comparison because of its functional difference.  But by the same token, if you're clearly using boolean `success` flags then I don't think someone should complain about the short style either.

(Regarding your first sentence though, I don't think it's bad to explicitly check for the boolean value true in a dynamically typed language, if that value is actually what you want.  It's only superfluous when static typing already constrains the variable to be a boolean.)

Comment: In this particular case the ajax call will return with some JSON data which is either the boolean `true` or some kind of error handling object. I guess it would be better to check for the error object and handle that and let the `true` case be the else block.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a function that can return `true` *or* a truthy value is a code smell.

Comment: Or the vastly more legible `if (items.size() > 0) { ... }`.

Answer (score 24):

With Javascript its worth knowing that beyond boolean true and false, values can be *truthy* and *falsy*.

Consider:

```
if (false)     // evaluates to false.
if (0)         // evaluates to false, 0 is falsy.
if ("")        // evaluates to false, empty strings are falsy.
if (null)      // evaluates to false, null values are falsy.
if (undefined) // evaluates to false, undefined values are falsy.
if (NaN)       // evaluates to false, NaN is falsy.
```

All other values for objects are truthy.

If truthy and falsy values are leading to errors in your logic, you should consider explicitly using `===` and `!==` operators to ensure objects are compared by type and value.

Answer (score 12):

Generally, you expect boolean variable names like:

```
success, enabled, pass
```

to have a true value. So

```
if(success) //or

if(enabled) //or

if(pass) //or

if(enabled) //or
```

is understandably and logically readable. But if you have variables like:

```
result, status, port1.bit7
```

it is better to write:

```
if(result == true) //or

if(status == false) //or

if(port1.bit7 == true)
```

because it is easily understood in that way than the example below:

```
if(result)
{
  ....
}
```

Readability is maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

What can go wrong? Exactly, nothing. In the best case your function does nothing. That's still better then having some random argument be accepted as `true`.

If you use `true` all the other time, then you should also check explicitly for it.

While I'm certain in favor of `if foo:` in Python, there is a big difference here and that is the fact that in the end some random jQuery programmer may come a long and thinks "Oh! It also works with a string and `new Boolean()`" and uses that.

Concerning Sean's suggestion to use `!!` it really depends whether you only want a boolean to be accepted or anything that's true. For a clean API I would only accept booleans though.

Answer (score 2):

To add to this conversation, sessionStorage and localStorage variables can only be stored as strings today, so if you use:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('completed',true);
```

It will actually be converted to a string and stored as 'true'.
I've seen many people writing methods and conversions to manipulate this value so that they can use an if statement using a boolean value, where a simple

```
if sessionStorage.getItem('completed') === 'true';
```

would suffice and is perfectly legible and maintainable in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I've read quite a bit about JavaScript, and I've never seen anyone say that `if(success)` was a bad practice. I would do it. Are you sure the `success` parameter will always be boolean? Right now, if that would ever change to something else, you'd have to edit the function. But if you just use `if(success)`, it would work for other "truthy" and "falsey" values, like a string vs. an empty string, or 1 vs 0.

If you want to convert whatever that parameter is to its boolean value, you can just double-negate it: `!!success`; but that's not necessary inside an conditional like that.

Comment: the success paramater was an arbitary object.

Answer (score 0):

Is it code smell or language smell or an implementation detail or a matter of convention?

Really, it depends on the situation.

Putting all false values and all true values into a bucket simplifies things, until the differences matters, be it bad code design or because it really does matter for some reason.

In the same vein Hoare apologized for inventing the `null` reference, which is as close to the root of this truthy problem as I see. JavaScript's design just confounds the issue by adding even more truthy values, leading many to just advocate explicit checking to avoid hard to track down errors (Douglas Crockford).  The JavaScript community has accepted the language itself, is a bit stuck. The Python core team advocates the the opposite as the language design seems to be set on simplifying things, not confounding them, and the core team is still planning for change in the language.  Small, iterative changes is the essence of large improvements over time, be it convention, or language design.

Both are good strategies for their particular situation. I am not saying that this is the exclusive source of improvement, but that is a major source of improvement at this time.

For example `True` and `False` are actually subclasses of an `int` in Python, 0 and 1 specifically.  This has several design benefits.  Then PEP8 advocates to prefer doing

```
if a_reference:
    pass
```

The only time `None` really even needs to be used in Python is when specifying an optional parameter.

```
def foo(bar=optional): # NOTE I made up this idealistic construct
    """Looks good at the surface"""
    pass

def foo(bar=None):
    """But this is clear to the programmer"""
    pass
```

JavaScript implicitly has all variables as optional:

```
function foo(x, y, z) {
    // Certainly not clear to the programmer.
}
```

And Crockford advocates explicitly checking things to try and add some clarity to the language.

```
if (foo === undefined) {
    // pass
}
```

Basically JavaScript added the Null Reference # 2, known as `undefined`.  I also think it is funny that the JavaScript language is so poorly considered by the programming community they think it is a fair trade off to add the complexity of using something like CoffeeScript, GWT, Pyjamas, just to have a better client side language.  Of course, I do not agree in the added complexity, but it is sadly true that some people may benefit, at least temporarily, and get the job at hand done faster, instead of dealing with JavaScript.

I do think this is a foolish decision in the long run, though.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best and simply solution is:

```
var isTrue = /^true$/.test( 'true' );    // true
var isTrue = /^true$/.test( 'false' );   // false
var isTrue = /^true$/.test( true );      // true
var isTrue = /^true$/.test( false );     // false
var isTrue = /^true$/.test( ' true ' );  // false
var isTrue = /^true$/.test( '' );        // false
var isTrue = /^true$/.test( 'prueba' );  // false
```